# why does adding a non volatile solute not decrease the boiling point?

Tags: physical-chemistry

If I add a solute that decreases the bond strength of the pure solvent then wouldn't the solvent molecules evaporate more easily as it has lesser force holding it down now?But in my textbook, it's written that BP always increases when we add a non-volatile solute.

Comment: At least some solvent interacts strongly with the solute, to use your picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decrease of the solvent activity due its decreased molar fraction is bigger than the solvent activity increase due eventual solvent solute interaction.

So the pressure versus solute molar fraction curve may not be linear as by the Raoult law, but is monotonous.